# GCloud SDK not creating application_default_credentials.json file in the correct folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Using the command `gcloud auth application-default login` gives the following confirmation message:

`Credentials saved to file: [C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]`

However, files are instead being created in this directory `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming\gcloud`.

Manually copying the file will get my code working. Is there any reason why the files are not being created in the correct folder?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but advice. Those credentials are created for and are managed by the CLI for the CLI. Your software should not be accessing them. Use a service account. If you continue to use them, you will affect your quotas, be rate limited, the SDK libraries will print warnings, etc.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same at my end and ran the command "gcloud auth application-default login" from my [Windows instance SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows) and the application_default_credentials.json file created at the correct location ( [C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json]). Please provide more information about your deployment scenario?